# Backslashes in posting data to a URL using CURL Php

Tags: php, post, curl

I am trying to post some data to a URL which contains double quotes.I escaped the quotes by adding back slashes.I just wanted to clarify will that be a problem while posting data.

```
$data = "{\"phoneNumber\":\"$no\",\"campid\":\"$refer\",\"simcards\":[{\"srno\":\"89914904040576482763\",\"mcc\":404,\"mnc\":49,\"operatorName\":\"airtel\",\"circleName\":\"AndhraPr\",\"msisdn\":\"\"},{\"srno\":\"89914904040874441867\",\"mcc\":404,\"mnc\":49,\"operatorName\":\"airtel\",\"circleName\":\"AndhraPr\",\"msisdn\":\"\"}]}";
```

If I shouldnt use backslashes ,what is the alternative.

Comment: simply use singles quotes on the outside and doube within

Answer (score 0):

just use single quotes outside then you dont have to escape the doubles inside

```
 $data = '{"phoneNumber":"'.$no.'","campid":"'.$refer.'","simcards":[{"srno":"89914904040576482763","mcc":404,"mnc":49,"operatorName":"airtel","circleName":"AndhraPr","msisdn":""},{"srno":"89914904040874441867","mcc":404,"mnc":49,"operatorName":"airtel","circleName":"AndhraPr","msisdn":""}]}';
```

Comment: Can we keep double quotes inside single ones?

Comment: the above is 100% valid, if thats what your asking